# (Basic) subtract and multiply within group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, math, data-manipulation

I would like to code the following in R per group of `X` :

(`Y`-1) * 1/3 * `Z`/100

Output for row 2 would therefore be: (2-1) * 1/3 * 25 / 100 = 0.083

Row 2 and 8 desired output also added as example

```
  X  Y   Z output   
1 A  1  25      0
2 A  2  25   0.08
3 A  3   0      0  
4 A  4  50    0.5
5 B  1   0      0
6 B  2   0      0
7 B  3   0      0
8 B  4 100      1
```

Thank you!!

Comment: why do you need  group by `with(df1, (Y-1) * 1/3 * Z /100)`  As the expected is only for two rows, not clear

Comment: its for a million rows actually

Comment: these are vectorized, so it should be comparatively efficient

Comment: Yes, I do this to rescale the Z value

Comment: Can youu please test the code on your data

Comment: Your calculation is based on each element and not based on  a group (unless I am wrong)

Comment: Unknown or uninitialised column: `with`.

Comment: `with` a `base R` function.  It is convenient to select columns without using `$` or `[[` or `[` i.e. if i don't use `with`.  the code would be `(df1$Y-1) * 1/3 * df1$Z/100`, Can you test the data on my post.

Comment: Oh... I forgot.. and I need the sum per group, that's what I meant. so `output2` for A would be 0.58 and for B 1

Comment: Try `df1[,  output := sum((Y-1) * 1/3 * Z /100), X]`

Comment: Error in `:=`("freq_value", sum(("category" - 1) * 1/3 * "data_value"/100)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: sorry, it is `setDT(df1)[,  output := sum((Y-1) * 1/3 * Z /100), X]` (as in my post)

Comment: I realize I need to group by X and a second variable, how could I do that? I will accept the answer right after!! Thank you so much for your help once again Akrun!!

Comment: what  is the second variable `setDT(df1)[,  output := sum((Y-1) * 1/3 * Z /100), .(X, secondvariable)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be made a bit more efficient in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,  output := sum((Y-1) * 1/3 * Z /100), X]
df1
#   X Y   Z    output
#1: A 1  25 0.5833333
#2: A 2  25 0.5833333
#3: A 3   0 0.5833333
#4: A 4  50 0.5833333
#5: B 1   0 1.0000000
#6: B 2   0 1.0000000
#7: B 3   0 1.0000000
#8: B 4 100 1.0000000
```

If we need to also group by another variable, specify it in a `list` with `.(`

```
setDT(df1)[,  output := sum((Y-1) * 1/3 * Z /100), by = .(X, year)]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(X) %>%
     mutate(output = sum((Y-1) * 1/3 * Z /100))
```

Or with more variables

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(X, year) %>%
     mutate(output = sum((Y-1) * 1/3 * Z /100))
```

NOTE: 'year' is not showed in the input data.  It is from OP's original data

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    Y = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Z = c(25L, 25L, 0L, 
    50L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 100L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "data.frame")
```